# CSS select second children and every third after it

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have a div with `n` children. I need to select the second element and every third after that, like so:

```
2, 5, 8, 11, 14, etc.
```

I was thinking it was something along the lines of `div.someclass:nth-child(2n+2)`.

Answer (score 7):

You can use `:nth-child(3n+2)`

Basically the 2 is where you want to start, and then you add 3 each time.

Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3qL8J/) with your example.

Comment: Damn, Eric beat me to it by 5 secs :)

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/nAttH/

```
 #outer div:nth-child(-n+5){
     background-color: blue;
 }
```

This is the way to go. Change 5 into the desired value.